# how do i repeat my function but instead use the next three values in the list?

Tags: python

if i type:

```
microcar(np.array([[45, 10, 10], [110, 10, 8], [60, 10, 5], [170, 10, 4]]), np.array([[47, 10, 15], [112, 9, 8.5], [50, 10, 8], [160, 8.5, 5]]))
```

it returns:

```
(52.53219888177297, 85.09035245341184, -148.85032037263932, 18.5359684117836, 100, 150.0)
```

which is good, however i want it to repeat this code for the next set of 3 values and so on e.g. `[110,10,8]` for the expected and `[50,10,8]` for the actual.

i can't figure how to incorporate a loop, where it treats the next set of 3 values as the new one to look at.

Also, cos(45) = 0.707106 (45 degrees) however it treats the cos(45) = 0.5253 (as radians) is there a way to convert the settings to degrees?

Below is my code

---

```py
import numpy as np

def microcar(expected, actual):
    horizontal_expected = expected[0,1]*expected[0,2]*np.cos(expected[0,0])
    vertical_expected = expected[0,1]*expected[0,2]*np.sin(expected[0,0])

    horizontal_actual = actual[0,1]*actual[0,2]*np.cos(actual[0,0])
    vertical_actual = actual[0,1]*actual[0,2]*np.sin(actual[0,0])

    distance_expected = expected[0,1]*expected[0,2]
    distance_actual = actual[0,1]*actual[0,2]


    return horizontal_expected, vertical_expected, horizontal_actual, vertical_actual, distance_expected, distance_actual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the inputs and loop over them like this

```py
import numpy as np

def microcar(expected, actual):
  l = zip(expected, actual)

  res = []
  for e in l:
    horizontal_expected = e[0][1]*e[0][2]*np.cos(e[0][0])
    vertical_expected = e[0][1]*e[0][2]*np.sin(e[0][0])
    horizontal_actual = e[1][1]*e[1][2]*np.cos(e[1][0])
    vertical_actual = e[1][1]*e[1][2]*np.sin(e[1][0])
    distance_expected = e[0][1]*e[0][2]
    distance_actual = e[1][1]*e[1][2]

    res.append([
      horizontal_expected,
      vertical_expected,
      horizontal_actual,
      vertical_actual,
      distance_expected,
      distance_actual
    ])

  return res

x = microcar(
  np.array([[45, 10, 10], [110, 10, 8], [60, 10, 5], [170, 10, 4]]),
  np.array([[47, 10, 15], [112, 9, 8.5], [50, 10, 8], [160, 8.5, 5]])
)

print(x)
```

The output:

```
[
  [52.53219888177297, 85.09035245341184, -148.85032037263932, 18.5359684117836, 100, 150.0],
  [-79.92166506517184, -3.539414246805677, 34.88163648998712, -68.08466373406274, 80, 76.5],
  [-47.62064902075782, -15.240531055110834, 77.19728227936906, -20.9899882963143, 50, 80.0],
  [37.51979008477766, 13.865978219881212, -41.46424579379759, 9.325573481107702, 40, 42.5]
]
```

I don't know what kind of output you expected, so this simply returns a list of lists with the results.

---

As for your question about [`np.cos`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html), it expects input in radians, so you could convert the degrees to radians through [`np.deg2rad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.deg2rad.html):

```
import numpy as np

print(np.cos(np.deg2rad(45))
# 0.7071067811865476
```

---

Without using `zip`, you can create a [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) equal to the length of one the arrays and loop over that, using the values (in this case `i`) to index into the arrays, in the following way

```py
import numpy as np

def microcar(expected, actual):
  res = []

  for i in range(len(expected)):
    horizontal_expected = expected[i,1]*expected[i,2]*np.cos(expected[i,0])
    vertical_expected = expected[i,1]*expected[i,2]*np.sin(expected[i,0])
    horizontal_actual = actual[i,1]*actual[i,2]*np.cos(actual[i,0])
    vertical_actual = actual[i,1]*actual[i,2]*np.sin(actual[i,0])
    distance_expected = expected[i,1]*expected[i,2]
    distance_actual = actual[i,1]*actual[i,2]

    res.append([
      horizontal_expected,
      vertical_expected,
      horizontal_actual,
      vertical_actual,
      distance_expected,
      distance_actual
    ])

  return res

x = microcar(
  np.array([[45, 10, 10], [110, 10, 8], [60, 10, 5], [170, 10, 4]]),
  np.array([[47, 10, 15], [112, 9, 8.5], [50, 10, 8], [160, 8.5, 5]])
)

print(x)
```

Output:

```
[
  [52.53219888177297, 85.09035245341184, -148.85032037263932, 18.5359684117836, 100, 150.0],
  [-79.92166506517184, -3.539414246805677, 34.88163648998712, -68.08466373406274, 80, 76.5],
  [-47.62064902075782, -15.240531055110834, 77.19728227936906, -20.9899882963143, 50, 80.0],
  [37.51979008477766, 13.865978219881212, -41.46424579379759, 9.325573481107702, 40, 42.5]
]
```

Note that this assumes that both inputs are of equal length. If they are not, you will likely encounter an `IndexError` exception. This assumption holds for `zip` as well, but there, you would "lose" the surplus entries in the longer array.

Comment: This is really good! but is there another way you can write it without using a zip? I'm not allowed to use it for my assignment as I haven't learnt it yet. As for converting the degrees to radians, when i type the above code it keeps coming up with error deg2rad not defined??

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution without `zip`. Also corrected the missing `np.` in front of `deg2rad`. On a sidenote: Another time, please note if it is a homework assignment, I would probably have hinted more at the answer, to help you figure it out yourself, rather than producing it outright.